# Reverse a specific slice of a list in Python

Tags: python, list, slice

I am trying to write a function that will receive a list and will return a list containing inverted elements between even and odd index. For example:

IP : [1,2,3,4]

OP : [2,1,4,3]

I don't understand why I get an `IndexError: list index out of range` error with the following code:

```
def mixed(list): 
 
  x = 0
  y = 2
  l = []

  for element in list: 
    mod_list = list[x:y]
    l.append(mod_list[1])
    l.append(mod_list[0]
    x += 2
    y += 2

  return l
```

The `l.append(mod_liste[1])` seems to be the issue...

Comment: Do you want end result like this OP : [2,1,4,3] ?

Comment: Yes! I'll edit for clarity @Uzair

Comment: Sure, Do you want me to fix it ? or I will rewrite for you with better approach ?

Comment: How many iterations the for-loop would make (if no error occurs) and which value will x and y have after the iterations?

Comment: @MichaelButscher it should have len(list) / 2 amount of iteration. So the loop should go thru the list once, swapping n0 & n1, n2 & n3, etc. By that logic, x will = len(list) and y = len(list) + 1

Comment: Correct, but your loop is iterating `len(list)` times...

Comment: @Uzair Thanks a lot for offering! I'd prefer to first understand my errors before getting the flushed out answer :)

Comment: @Nick would you mind explaining why that's causing the IndexError?

Comment: @AwesomePossum because when you get to the third iteration of the loop (when there should have only been two) the value of `x` is 4, which is an invalid index for `list`.

Comment: As an aside, don't use built-in type names (`list`) for variables; you override their functionality and make them unusable.

Comment: I make correction in your code. You can check it. how I fixed Index by controlling loop iteration.

Comment: @Nick thanks, you actually helped me figured our my issue with your comment. Noted for the built in name (`list`) too!

Answer (score 2):

You can use built-in functions and slicing for that:

```
from itertools import chain

L = [1,2,3,4]
list(chain(*zip(L[1::2],L[::2]))) # [2,1,4,3]
```

Comment: Note that this won't work if your list has odd length (but neither does your own solution, and it's not clear either if this case should be supported and what should be the output then...)

Comment: Brother I will not work on ODD length of list.

Comment: You need a little fixed for ODD list too.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use build-in function. Just make your loop stop when y is greater than list length. Make check for odd list.

```
def mixed(list):

x = 0
y = 2
l = []

for element in list:
    mod_list = list[x:y]
    l.append(mod_list[1])
    l.append(mod_list[0])
    x += 2
    y += 2
    if y > list.__len__() and list.__len__()%2 == 0:
        break
    elif y > list.__len__() and list.__len__()%2 != 0:
        l.append(list[y-2])
        break

return l
```

Comment: What's the deal with using ugly `list.__len__()` instead of common `len(list)`?

Comment: both are same. According to python docs, __len__() method always work.